# n quadratic equations with n variables

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

I have a system of n quadratic equations with n unknown variables $a_1,...,a_n$  that can be written as followed:

$
\begin{pmatrix}a_1\\a_2\\\vdots\\a_n\end{pmatrix}^TB_i\begin{pmatrix}a_1\\a_2\\\vdots\\a_n\end{pmatrix}=g_i 
$

$i=1,...,n$

- $B_i$ are known $n\times n$ matrices
- the $g_i$ are known as well
- $n$ is even

For $n=2$ this is easy to solve by simply multiplying the matrix and vectors out and then doing some basic algebra.

However with $n=4$ or higher the amount of computing time by this method gets quite excessive and I was wondering if there is a simpler algorithm to obtain the $a_i$ ?

Comment: Do you seek real solutions?

Comment: @Icv No, the $a_i$ can be complex

Answer (score 1):

The parity of $n$ has nothing to do here.

Let $X=[a_1,\cdots,a_n]^T$. If the $(B_i),(g_i)$ are generic (for example, randomly choose them), then the number of complex solutions $X$ is $2^n$.

To find explicit solutions, we can use Grobner basis method. We solve an algebraic system of $n$ equations of degree $2$ in the $n$ unknowns $(a_i)$.

That works in less than $18"$ until $n=6$ ($64$ solutions).

The Grobner decomposition reduces the original system to a system of the form (when $n=6$).

$P(a_1)=0,a_2=Q_2(a_1),\cdots,a_n=Q_n(a_1)$ where $degree(P)=64,degree(Q_i)=63$.

Thus, solving $P(a_1)=0$, we obtain approximations of the $64$ complex values of $a_1$; the sequel is easy.

EDIT. Answer to the OP. That follows is an example, when $n=4$, solved -using Maple- in 0"2 (of course, the hidden calculations are very complicated). The system of $4$ equations in the unknowns $(x_i)$ has LHS

[image]

.

The polynomial, the roots of which, are the $2^4=16$ complex solutions in $x_1$ is

[image]

The other functions (I don't write them) give $x_2,x_3,x_4$ as polynomials in $x_1$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However I don't really know how to apply any of what you suggested for my problem. I'll read into in but could you show how to use Grobner basis method for an example of, say, two simple $2 \times 2$ matrices?

Comment: I'll give you an example in a moment.